# R: retrieving data using RCurl and postForm

Tags: r, web-scraping, rcurl

I am trying to scrape some data from a web site. This is the kind of thing that I would usually do in Perl, but I would really like to wean myself off Perl. (I'm not dissing Perl; it's been a valuable tool but I am distressed by how much I still struggle with the language after more than a decade.) As my needs are simple and performance is seldom an issue for me, I want to shift my web scraping to R. I know some R but I have never used RCurl or similar libraries.

The task is to scrape a database of publicly available data. The issue is complicated by my not knowing exactly how to pass the arguments, as I am just looking at the JS source and trying to work out what to include in the RCurl postForm request. The code below does not throw any obvious errors, but neither does it return anything useful.

Q. What am I doing wrong?

[Edited: to reflect changes suggested, but not yet resolved]

```
require(RCurl)
## -----------> Form:
## http://jamaserv.jama.or.jp/newdb/eng/index.html
## -----------> Result:
## http://jamaserv.jama.or.jp/newdb/eng/prod4/prod4TsMkEntry.html

#POST /newdb/eng/prod4/prod4TsMkEntry.html makerCd=5&additionBase=1&additionInterval=1&chkSelCnd3=0&car4Cd=100005&termFrom=201103&termTo=201203&prod4TsMkEntryForm%3AdoAction=Server&prod4TsMkEntryForm%2Feng%2Fprod4%2Fprod4TsMkEntry.html=prod4TsMkEntryForm

#POST /newdb/eng/prod4/prod4TsMkEntry.html?pass chkSelCnd3=0&prod4TsMkEntryForm%2Feng%2Fprod4%2Fprod4TsMkEntry.html=prod4TsMkEntryForm&makerCd=5&additionBase=1&termTo=201203&prod4TsMkEntryForm%3AdoAction=Server&additionInterval=1&termFrom=201103&car4Cd=100005

x <- postForm('http://jamaserv.jama.or.jp/newdb/eng/prod4/prod4TsMkEntry.html?pass',
              chkSelCnd3 = '0',
              'prod4TsMkEntryForm/eng/prod4/prod4TsMkEntry.html' = 'prod4TsMkEntryForm',
              makerCd = '5',
              additionBase = '1',
              termTo = '201203',
              'prod4TsMkEntryForm:doAction' = 'Server',
              additionInterval = '1',
              termFrom = '201103',
              car4Cd = '100005',
              .opts = curlOptions(
              referer = 'http://jamaserv.jama.or.jp/newdb/eng/prod4/prod4TsMkEntry.html',
              verbose = TRUE,
              header = TRUE,
              followLocation = TRUE,
              useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13'
  )
)
```

When using a browser the form looks like this:
[image]

And the above settings return (on a separate page) this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a far more complex problem that it originally appeared, involving server-side Javascript and all kinds of stuff. It doesn't seem feasible with the simple approach I used in this question. So, answering my own question and moving on...

Comment: ＠DWin Unfortunately I have no code that comes close to working. After I gave up on an R-based solution I turned it over to two different Perl specialists with good scraping chops and after much messing around the problem defeated both of them. So for now it goes into the "too hard" bucket. Maybe in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `.opts` argument, 
to specify the referer 
(some websites reject the query if it comes from outside),
a user-agent (some websites reject unknown user-agents)
and ask to follow the redirection (that is why your result was empty).
There is more information if you add `verbose=TRUE`: 
the initial POST query actually fails,
before the contents of the form are sent,
and RCurl tries a GET query instead, 
which returns an error message
("Type (Motor Vehicle) is not selected").

```
x <- postForm(
  ...,
  .opts = curlOptions(
    referer="http://jamaserv.jama.or.jp/newdb/eng/prod4/prod4TsMkEntry.html",
    verbose = TRUE, 
    followLocation = TRUE,
    useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13"
  )
)
```

Comment: @"Vincent Zoonekynd" thank you for these pointers. Two clarifications if you would be so kind (1) How can I access the error response from RCurl? As you can see, really am a newbie in this (2) Do I just add the opts argument to the end of the existing request, like any other argument? I tried that and it didn't seem to work for me. I got `Error in merge(list(...), .opts) : argument is missing, with no default`. (Also think there should be a comma after the followLocation argument?)

Comment: (1) Just add `header=TRUE`. (2) The (cryptic) error message was due to a spurious comma after `useragent`.

Comment: "@Vincent Zoonekynd" Using the (revised) code above in the question I get as far as the error page, which is a big step forward. Using Live HTTP headers to observe the POST that the website generates it seems that all the arguments are identical. I'm perplexed. Unless there is obviously something wrong with the way I've structured my request it looks like we've been defeated on this one. (Incidentally that "Type (Motor Vehicle) is not selected" error was due to a typo in one of my arguments, now fixed, thanks.)